# Oracle Apex workspace settings for multiple sessions for the same user account

Tags: oracle-apex

## Making Faster Navigation Between APEX Site-Designer Pages

I am having a few difficulties here as this may be a setting that I took for granted in other previous versions of Oracle APEX as before it may have been a default setting, but now the default has changed.  Can anyone help me figure it out?  I also explain why it was useful for me before...

> How do you enable the Oracle APEX instance to permit logging in to the site-designer pages for a single workspace (Application Builder, SQL Workshop, Team Development modules, etc.) using the same user id through more than one browser window?

Note,  I do this to save time from navigating between each section of the site-designer (even quick load times can slow down developing an application page or region because of constant shuttling back and forth to make small changes originally missing).

---

### Example Use Case:

**Oracle APEX Release:** *Application Express 4.2.6.00.03*
**Database Platform:**  *Oracle 11g R2*
**Client-Agent(Browser):** *Firefox Release 33*

> Note, this was a fresh install from a lower version that was upgraded
> several times up to the current APEX release.

1. **LOG IN** to Site-Designer with an account that has DEVELOPER or ADMIN level user privileges.
2. **USE** your own values for WORKSPACE, USER, PASSWORD.
3. **CREATE** a new PAGE level OBJECT (REGION, FORM, REPORT, etc.) and stop in the middle of the set-up wizard.
4. RIGHT-CLICK on a TOP LEVEL Menu item such as SQL WORKSHOP.  Open it in a NEW WINDOW;
5. CREATE an object like a TABLE which can be used by the DESIGN WIZARD open in step 3.

> The reason for trying to keep different browser sessions open for the same USER account allows users to go back to another section of the design tool to build other objects or app/page elements that were overlooked before initiating a design wizard process.

**Observed Behavior:**
The new session will allow the user to make a new database object, but when clicking back on the previous window with the session that is running the original wizard, the server prompts for a new log in because that session has been closed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found when facing a similar situation was opening Apex in a couple of different web browsers in parallel, so i have Safari for the SQL workshop, and Chrome for the page designer..

so instead of ctrl-tab i use cmd-tab (or alt-tab for PC)

Our IT said it has something to do with session state..